# Keras EarlyStopping callback working inconsistently

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, talos

For training my neural network model I use Keras' `EarlyStopping` callback to minimize train time (via `talos.utils.early_stopper` wrapper):

```
history = model.fit(x=X_train, 
                    y=y_train, 
                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val), 
                    batch_size=params["batch"], 
                    epochs=params["epoch"], 
                    callbacks=[talos.utils.early_stopper(epochs=params["epoch"], mode='strict', min_delta=0.001)], 
                    verbose=1)
```

However, I'm noticing that it's working rather inconsistently:

**Exhibit A**

```
Epoch 1/42
160/160 [==============================] - 19s 73ms/step - loss: 116.8279 - accuracy: 0.3124 - val_loss: 0.5561 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 2/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.5676 - accuracy: 0.3440 - val_loss: 0.5564 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 3/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 35ms/step - loss: 0.5720 - accuracy: 0.3337 - val_loss: 0.5573 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
-> TRAIN STOPS
```

**Exhibit B**

```
Epoch 14/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5664 - accuracy: 0.3501 - val_loss: 0.5581 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 15/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5684 - accuracy: 0.3414 - val_loss: 0.5575 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 16/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5699 - accuracy: 0.3348 - val_loss: 0.5570 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 17/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5686 - accuracy: 0.3415 - val_loss: 0.5567 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 18/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 38ms/step - loss: 0.5666 - accuracy: 0.3457 - val_loss: 0.5566 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 19/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5694 - accuracy: 0.3367 - val_loss: 0.5563 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 20/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5671 - accuracy: 0.3418 - val_loss: 0.5562 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 21/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5654 - accuracy: 0.3472 - val_loss: 0.5561 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 22/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5673 - accuracy: 0.3416 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 23/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5637 - accuracy: 0.3542 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 24/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5670 - accuracy: 0.3417 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 25/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 38ms/step - loss: 0.5652 - accuracy: 0.3495 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 26/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5663 - accuracy: 0.3454 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 27/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 38ms/step - loss: 0.5679 - accuracy: 0.3384 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 28/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 38ms/step - loss: 0.5639 - accuracy: 0.3505 - val_loss: 0.5560 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 29/42
160/160 [==============================] - 7s 42ms/step - loss: 0.5636 - accuracy: 0.3515 - val_loss: 0.5559 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 30/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5680 - accuracy: 0.3399 - val_loss: 0.5559 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 31/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5696 - accuracy: 0.3338 - val_loss: 0.5559 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 32/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 0.5705 - accuracy: 0.3321 - val_loss: 0.5559 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
Epoch 33/42
160/160 [==============================] - 6s 40ms/step - loss: 0.5724 - accuracy: 0.3273 - val_loss: 0.5559 - val_accuracy: 0.3708
-> TRAIN STOPS
```

Why is it on Exhibit B it didn't stop earlier even though it's clearly seen that there's no improvement on `val_loss` above `min_delta`? I've looked at `talos` [source](https://github.com/autonomio/talos/blob/master/talos/model/early_stopper.py) and it seems to me that `early_stopper` is just a wrapper for the callback and everything looks fine. I also noticed that this only tends to happen every time `val_loss` floats around `0.5559 - 0.5560`.

FWIW I'm running this on Colab, utilizing TPU.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested by not using any wrapper? Is it the same?

Comment: Is the stopping criterion `val_loss` and not difference in `loss` between epochs?

Comment: @M.Innat Yes: `0.5603 -> 0.5591 -> 0.5582  -> 0.5576 -> 0.5571 -> 0.5568 -> STOP`. Shouldn't it stopped earlier at `0.5576`?
@pavel Yes, the default `monitor` parameter is `val_loss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, changing `monitor` from `val_loss` to `val_accuracy` (`EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuracy", min_delta=0.01, patience=2, verbose=1, mode='auto'`) seems to give a more consistent callback.